In a multiline equation, how to align from the right in a second-level split?
I have a long equation, where I want to divide the expression into 4 parts, 2 of which are & aligned, and the other two are child to the former, and should be aligned from the right.
I am nesting a equation and a split environment with an alignment & sign on the integrals (see code and figure). I would like the line split of the integrands, however, to align from the right, without creating an Overfull box.
I achieve an alignment from the right with two multlined environments in each split cell. However, they are creating an Overfull \hbox. How can I avoid this? What am I missing? And how can I make this minimal, and within best practices?


\documentclass[12pt]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    R(\tau) = \frac{\lambda^2}{P(t)} \bigg(&
    \int_{t_0}^{\tau} \dd{t} \eta(t)
    \int_{t_0}^{\tau} \dd{t'} \eta(t')
    \abs{\alpha}^2
    \begin{multlined}[t]
        \Big[
            M\{
                q e^{-\mathrm{i} g (t' - t)}
                \ev{f(x') f(y)}
            \} \\
            + \frac{e^{-\mathrm{i} g (t' - t)}}{2}
            \Big(
                p \ev{ f(x') f(x) }
                + (1-p) \ev{ f(y') f(y) }
            \Big)
        \Big]
    \end{multlined}
    \\
    &- \int_{t_0}^{\tau} \dd{t} \eta(t)
    \int_{t_0}^{t} \dd{t'} \eta(t')
    \abs{\beta}^2
    \begin{multlined}[t]
        \Big[
            M\{
            (p + q) e^{-\mathrm{i} g (t' - t)}
            \ev{f(x) f(x')}
            \} \\
            + M\{
            ( 1 - p + q^* ) e^{-\mathrm{i} g (t' - t)}
            \ev{f(y) f(y')} \}
        \Big]
        \bigg) ,
    \end{multlined}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}


